# Javascript/jQuery wait for variable true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following setup:

- A document can have multiple forms.
- When the input on an `input` field changes, `jQuery` will fire an `ajax` event. And `input.data("checking", true)` is called.
- When the `ajax` event has been finished, `input.data("checking", false)` is called.

Now I want to make a custom `form` `submit` that waits for all `input` in this `form` to be on `input.data("checking") === true`.

My code so far, without the question applied:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {


    event.target.checkValidity();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    //TODO: prevent this when not everything is checked
    var dataSerialized = $(this).serialize();
    var service = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: "services/" + service + ".php",
        data: dataSerialized,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            if (html == "1") {
                //TODO: load page from json callback
                //loadPage(onsuccess);
            }
            else {
                loadPage("error");
            }
        },
        error: function(html, message) {
            finalError(message);
        }
    });
});
```

How could I make this function wait (non-blocking!) until **all** ajax events are finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose to create a function `checkDone` which returns `true` when `input.data("checking") == false` for all `input` in the form, you could do:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
    event.target.checkValidity();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var that = $(this);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(checkDone(that)) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            var dataSerialized = that.serialize();
            var service = that.attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: "services/" + service + ".php",
                data: dataSerialized,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    if (html == "1") {
                        //TODO: load page from json callback
                        //loadPage(onsuccess);
                    }
                    else {
                        loadPage("error");
                    }
                },
                error: function(html, message) {
                    finalError(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

In this way you check every 0.5 seconds if you can submit the form after all inputs are validated, and if so the interval is cleared and the form submitted.

**However I would recommend not to remove standard server side validation on post submit.**

Comment: This cannot block the browser, right? In modern browsers everything should run in seperate threads. And don't worry, there's also server side validation, this is just for user experience.

Comment: This should not block the browser, no, but I haven't had chance to test it.